# Loops & Handling Data Entry Errors

Tags: java

I am attempting to create a Java program that will allow the user to enter any desired amount of numerical grades and then calculate the `MIN`, `MAX` & `Average`. Handling input errors is where it gets confusing for me.

I've come up with two different approaches, the first allowing the user to enter their desired number of grades until the user enters sentinel `-1`. The second approach prompts the user to enter the number of grades beforehand.

```
// APPROACH ONE:
double grade = 0;
while (grade != -1) {
    grade = input.nextDouble();
}

// APPROACH TWO:
System.out.println("Enter number of grades: ");
double num = input.nextDouble();
for (int i = 1, i <= num, i++) {           
    System.out.println("Enter grade: ");                
    double grade = input.nextDouble();
}
```

I need to incorporate messages to alert user when numbers outside parameters are entered- lettesr, words, etc. When I try to implement these error handling loops, I can't figure out how to get the loops to ignore errored responses.

For example, in my Approach Two, if the user enters 3 grades, and then enters `89.5`, `93.4`, `-1`, my program just ends because it thinks that `-1` is apart of the 3 grades.

I can't figure how to get it to recognize the -1, display error, and then prompt for one more entry to total 3. Perhaps Approach One would be easier since there is no set number of grades that is predetermined.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I usually use a while loop, which would look something like this:

```
double num = input.nextDouble();
for (int i = 1, i <= num, i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter grade:  ");
    double grade = input.nextDouble();

    while(grade < 0.0 || grade > 100.0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid imput. Please reenter grade number " + n);
        grade = input.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

This will put the user into a loop that they cannot get out of until they enter a number between 0 and 100, and the n value in the for loop will not update until they enter a valid number.

Answer (score 0):

To give warning messages to users you probably want to experiment with `try/catch` statements (exception handling) and also include booleans as controls for while loops. Also seeing that your code requires the user to enter a few numbers I assume you would need to use some sort of `array/arraylist` to help calculate min/max/avg. Hence your code may turn out to be something like this:

```
public static ArrayList<Double> getdouble(ArrayList<Double> a){
    boolean control = true;
    boolean control2 = true;
    double grade = 0;
    while (control == true){

        while (control2 == true){
            System.out.println("enter grade or -1 to end");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            try {
                grade = input.nextDouble();
                if (grade == -1){
                    control2 = false;
                    break;
                }
                a.add(grade);
            } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("error");
                    control2 = false;
            }
        } // end control2

        System.out.println("input Y to continue adding grades or any other button to exit");
            Scanner input2 = new Scanner (System.in);
            if (input2.nextLine().toUpperCase().equals("Y")){
                control2 = true;
            } else {
                control = false;
            }
    } //end control
    return a;
}

public static void main(String [] args){

    ArrayList<Double> x = new ArrayList<Double>();
    getdouble(x);
    System.out.println(x);
}
```